# In LYX, how do I set up two independent viewers for the same file format?

Tags: pdf, lyx, viewers

I would like to have two independent file viewers for SumatraPDF and Acrobat using the same file format (pdflatex=pdf2).
What is the easiest way to achieve this?

The viewer seems to be connected to the file format so I either use one or the other right not. But I would love to be able to switch between the two!

Sumatra gives you forward and inverse search, but Acrobat prints nicely.

Comment: In Sumatra you can open a file in Reader by selecting File --> Open in Adobe Reader. So you could use Sumatra as default, and if you want to check how it looks in Reader, or print it, use that feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you can set your own program as a PDF viewer, the easiest is to write a script that calls both viewers, and to instruct LyX to use this script as PDF viewer.  If you are under Unix, the script would be something like

```
#!/usr/bash
sumatraPDF "$@" &
acroread "$@" &
```

However, you are probably using Windows: in that case you could create a batch file with something like

```
start "sumatraPDF" "/path/to/sumatraPDF.exe %1 %2"
start "Acrobat" "/path/to/acrobat.exe %1 %2"
```